# json object push data angular

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs

I am stuck with adding a data in json object api. Can I add a new data with push in object json ? it doesnt add a new object in json api

```
app.controller('InventoryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://api.bos.lv/api/v1/inventory/?format=json'}).success( function(data){
        $scope.info = data; // response data 
    });

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.info.objects.push({"name":$scope.newinfo.name, "description":$scope.newinfo.description, "location":$scope.newinfo.location, "status":$scope.newinfo.status});
    };
    $scope.newinfo = {};
});
```

json file where i get the data from http

```
{
  meta: {
  limit: 20,
  next: null,
  offset: 0,
  previous: null,
  total_count: 1
 },
  objects: [
      {
         count: 2,
          created: "2014-02-20T09:01:15.285510",
          description: "Camelion 2300mAh",
          id: 1,
          location: "IT nodala",
          name: "Baterija AA",
          published: true,
          resource_uri: "/api/v1/inventory/1",
          slug: "baterija-aa",
          status: "good condition"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it doesnt add a new object in json api

Comment: Do you get any error with the push operation? If not, it is probably your server. What server generates the json?

Comment: django, tastypie api  dont have any errors... maybe i should use http POST or something ? can i add object using push ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only making the change on the client side. You have to post/put your changes. Of course, you have to support the request on your server.

```
$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.info.objects.push({"name":$scope.newinfo.name, "description":$scope.newinfo.description, "location":$scope.newinfo.location, "status":$scope.newinfo.status});

    $http.post('http://api.bos.lv/api/v1/inventory/', $scope.info).success(successCallback);
};
```

[Angular $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

You may want to have a separate service to perform these HTTP requests.

Comment: Have you implemented the POST request method on your server? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

Comment: `<form ng-submit="add()"  method="POST">...</form` can i do like this ?

Comment: You are still talking of the client-side. When you post to the server, there should be a method there to handle your post request.

Comment: `$http.post('http://api.bos.lv/api/v1/inventory/', $scope.info).success(function(data) {
           $scope.info.push({"name":$scope.newinfo.name});
   $scope.newinfo = "";
        });`  something like this ?